# REST api - How should the client supply userid to the request URL for its user resource?

Tags: rest, web, webserver, token, jwt

A client needs to login with a username/password the first time. A JWT token is returned for future requests. The token will have a userid so that the server can fetch the user's resource from the database.

The problem I have is the client needs to form the request URL to update its resource let's say POST /users/{userid}. How should I get the userid for the client? I can't access the JWT token which is stored in a httpOnly secure cookie. Should I store the userid on the client somehow? So that it can use it for the URL?

Comment: If you are responsible for the api, why can't you get the user information on the server side from the token?

Comment: I can do that, but how should the URL look like if I want to follow REST? I initially thought to POST to /users but shouldn't the URL specifically target a resource i want to change? Maybe POST /users/self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem now.  You are afraid of losing some of the advantages of a RESTFUL api, a unique resource locator,

I often have a set of URIs that start with the path that indicates that operations are on the currently authenticated user.

```
/current/profile
/current/blog_posts
```

In such cases I pull the user out of the request context on the server, which I can get by parsing the JWT token.

And when I want to operate on other users I use the identifier instead

```
/{{user_id}}/profile
/{{user_id}}/blog_posts
```

I'm not sure whether this is strictly RESTFUL, but it does give users of my API a stable and discoverable URI. I've used this pattern with a number of projects and teams without complaint.

If you really must get a user identifier two ideas idea comes to mind:

- Return the user_id along with the jwt token.
- Make an extra API call
  to get the user_id from the server and then use that for all
  subsequent calls.

Oh, another option comes to mind.  Change your notion of a user_id and use the username (which you already have) instead.